# How to use my own class in main?

Tags: java, javafx, borderpane

I got a school assignment that is driving me nuts. I can find the answer im looking for while searching the web, so I really would appriciate some advice on this one.

The assignment is to create a basic JavaFX Application that says "Hello World" but i should contain of the helloMain.java and the class HelloWorld.java that extends BorderPane. I have solved the assignment just using the helloMain but when I have tried to move some of the code (the root node and all it contains) into the HelloWorld.java the Scene does not seem to load when I run the application (just an empty window). So obviously I have done something wrong, but I cant figure out what.

in helloJava I got the following code (and Im pretty sure this is correct)

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class helloWorldMain extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        HelloWorld helloWorld = new HelloWorld();
        Scene scene = new Scene(helloWorld, 300, 300);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);

    }

}
```

And in my HelloWorld.java i got this code

```
public class HelloWorld extends BorderPane {

public HeloWorld() {
    final Text text = new Text(0, 130, "Hello World");
    Pane txtPane = new Pane();
    Pane txtPane2 = new Pane();         

    VBox root = new VBox();
    txtPane.getChildren().add(text);
    txtPane2.getChildren().add(text);

    root.getChildren().addAll(txtPane, txtPane2);

}
```

}

I think it is pretty safe to say that I dont really know what I am doing, but im trying to learn.

1. What am I missing in the HelloWorld class? is it something in the constructor? or should I use some kind of fields? or is it something else?
2. I have been searching for hours trying to solve this problem, but I dont find any search result that is related to what I am trying to do.. Where can I read about "this approach" (dont really know what it is called, and probably why I could not find anything) when you create your own class and trying to use it in main?

Lots of code love to the one who can help me understand this :)

Comment: if your public class is called `helloWorldMain` it should be in a file named `helloWorldMain.java` (note that by Java naming conventions type names should start with uppercase: `HelloWorldMain`)

Comment: Thanks will correct that :)

Comment: The file is named "correctly" in terms of the class has the same name as the file (it is correct for the JVM), but in Java by convention Class names and therefore file names (with ext of .java) shall be started with uppercase character, so rename the class and the file also to "HelloWorldMain".

Comment: You should also get a compiler error on the spelling mistake in your constructor: `HeloWorld`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `HelloWorld` you add `Node`s to a `VBox` that you don't add anywhere, so they are "hanging in the air".

Add this line to the end of constructor of HelloWorld
...

```
getChildren().add(root);
```

... and you are done.

Comment: That's not everthing. Tobias creates a ``HelloWorld`` instance in his ``helloWorldMain``, but he doesn't add that to the content either. So what's also missing is to add ``helloWorld`` to ``scene``.

Comment: `HelloWorld helloWorld = new HelloWorld();

Scene scene = new Scene(helloWorld, 300, 300);

primaryStage.setScene(scene);

primaryStage.show();`

It's correct.

Comment: Oh god, I didn't see that. Not enough coffee yet.

Comment: Wow, thanks alot! I been sitting with the for 4 hours. So really thanks! Could you explain this a bit more to me? When using the snippet you posted, whos children is it that Im getting?

Edit: Wrong above, I mean who is the parent?

Comment: @TobiasBredenberg the children of the ``BorderPane`` that your ``HelloWorld`` extends. Extending classes lets you use their methods.

Comment: @TobiasBredenberg Would it be more clear, if `this.getChildren().add(root);` was used?

Comment: aah! Thanks! Now I got it! :)

Comment: @fabian : Exactly the same that I wanted to comment:)

here "this": "is a BorderPane" as you inherit from that, and inheritance means "is-a" relation.

Comment: Will mark your answer as correct, I just have to wait 7 more minutes :)

Comment: Seems like I got a other problem, if you know the answer to that as well. My panes are ontop of each other, (overlaying) the last one should be under the first one. How do I fix that? and why does it happen first now when I am using my own class?

Comment: Hm, I haven't noticed something. You create Text instance like this:

`final Text text = new Text(0, 130, "Hello World");`

Then you add it to 2 containers that shall not happen.

What I would do to create two Labels:
`Label label1 = new Label("HelloWorld");
Label label2 = new Label("HelloWorld");`

Then I would not create `Pane` objects, rather add the labels directly do the `VBox`:

`root.getChildren().addAll(txtPane, txtPane2);`

VBox will solve the layouting for the labels inside then.